# URL Replacement in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to change a value in a string that's holding my current URL. I'm trying to get something like

```
http://myurl.com/test/begin.php?req=&srclang=english&destlang=english&service=MyMemory
```

to look like

```
http://myurl.com/test/end.php?req=&srclang=english&destlang=english&service=MyMemory
```

replacing `begin.php` for `end.php`.

I need the `end.php` to be stored in a variable so it can change, but `begin.php` can be a static string.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
$endURL   = 'end.php';
$beginURL = 'begin.php';
$newURL   = str_ireplace($beginURL,$endURL,$url);
```

---

EDIT:
Also, if I wanted to replace

```
http://myurl.com/begin.php?req=&srclang=english&destlang=english&service=MyMemory
```

with

```
http://newsite.com/end.php?req=&srclang=english&destlang=english&service=MyMemory
```

then how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Well, that should have worked. What is the content of `$url`? Are you sure it's what you expect? http://codepad.org/kEjcMqYL

Comment: I'm not savvy with regex, but this can help when testing your statements http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to replace the script filename of the url, you can use something like this :

```
<?php 
  $endURL   = 'end.php';
  $url ="http://myurl.com/test/begin.php?req=&srclang=english&destlang=english&service=MyMemory";
  $pattern = '/(.+)\/([^?\/]+)\?(.+)/';
  $replacement = '${1}/'.$endURL.'?${3}';
  $newURL = preg_replace($pattern , $replacement, $url);

   echo "url : $url <br>";
   echo "newURL : $newURL <br>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you want them to get to end.php from beigin.php? Seems like you can just to a FORM submit to end.php and pass in the variables via POST or GET variables.

The only way to change what page (end.php, begin.php) a user is on is to link them to another page from that page, this requires a page refresh.

Comment: Or a `header("Location: ...");` call, as long as headers hasn't already been sent.

Answer (score 0):

I recently made a PHP-file for this, it ended up looking like this:

```
$vars = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
$filename = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$filename = substr($filename, 4);
// for me substr removed 'abc/' in the beginning of the string, you can of course adjust this variable, this is the "end.php"-variable for you.

if (strlen($vars) > 0) $vars = '?' . $vars;
$resultURL = "http://somewhere.com" . $filename . $vars;
```